# Need some vim advice on switching to python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim

I'm using Vim as my primary editor/IDE for all of my Django projects. Using YouCompleteMe, syntastic and a couple of other plug-ins. The experience is fantastic.

I've decided to start all new projects with python3 as the world is moving to Py3K. But vim is not playing right with both versions of python.

I'm compiled with both versions of python.

```
vim --version | grep python
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3/dyn     +vreplace
```

YouCompleteMe don't support python3 yet. jedi-vim works with both versions but I'm not just getting it right.

Usually without any plugins I can invoke any of py/py3 command. But enabling jedi-vim it automatically calls system python2.

I'm using Vundle as vim plug-in manager.

If you please share your vimrc/other configurations/workarounds to use vim for python3 development (or both versions) that'll very helpful for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there anything Django-specific to this question? (For example, does YouCompleteMe have extra functionality to support Django projects or something?) If not, you should remove the tag; you want to attract answers from everyone who's an expert in Python 3.x and vim, even if they know nothing about Django. (By the way, I added the `python-3.x` tag for you, which you definitely want.)

Comment: Thanks. I've removed django tag.

Comment: Are you only using this for python3 development? Do you have any plugins that actually require python3? Make sure you read `:help python-2-and-3`, there are cases (when symbol collide in the interpreter) that cause the second interpreter to fail to load. (Only the first interpreter called will be loaded). It seems like you only really need python (2) support in the question.

Comment: @FDinoff: "I've decided to start all new projects with python3". So it sounds like he definitely needs Python 3 support. (But if he wants to continue editing his old projects, he also needs Python 2 support.)

Comment: @abarnert I don't see why vim needs to be running with python 3 plugins for him to edit python 3 files. (or vice versa for python 2 files.) The editor need python to run the plugins not to edit anything. So unless there is a specific plugin he wants to use that requires python3 I don't see a reason to change this. The only reason I can see is if he is using the py3 commands to run his python 3 files, otherwise he does not need an embedded python3 interpreter. (Even if he is I feel that would be unstable since the py3 commands store state between calls).

Comment: @FDinoff: But he says he _is_ executing `py` and `py3` commands, and presumably needs to do so. In fact, it sounds like that's his whole problem: "Usually without any plugins I can invoke any of py/py3 command. But enabling jedi-vim it automatically calls system python2."

Answer (score 5):

As other people point out in comments, you don't need to change much in terms of Vim config in order to switch to Python3.  What you do need to do is identify plugins that use the embedded Python(s), find out which of them support both Python2 and Python3 and tell them to prefer Python3, and phase out those that only work with Python2.

For the plugins I'm using:

- gundo: `let g:gundo_prefer_python3 = 1`
- jedi: `let g:jedi#force_py_version = 3`
- syntastic: `let g:syntastic_python_python_exec = 'python3'`, and install the Python3 versions of all checkers
- python-mode: `let g:pymode_python = 'python3'`
- YouCompleteMe: doesn't work with Python3.

<del>Also, nice to have if you plan to edit VimL files with `py` and `py3` commands: install the excellent [SyntaxRange](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4168), and add this to `after/syntax/vim.vim`:</del>

<del>`call SyntaxRange#Include('\C\v<py\%(thon)?3?\s+\<\<\s*[A-Z]{3,}\zs$', '\C\v^[A-Z]{3,}$', 'python')`</del>

Comment: Thanks for recommending my plugin! But doesn't the built-in `syntax/vim.vim` support embedded Python (2/3) blocks already (configurable via `g:vimsyn_embed`)?

Comment: @Ingo Karkat: I didn't know about that.  Apparently I have a plugin that interferes with it, which is why I didn't notice it's supposed to work by default.  Ok, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still need switching to Python 3, this is what I found.

Vim can be compiled with both Python 2 and Python 3 support, but it will dynamically load only 1 version of Python, whichever got called first. It means if you have some plugins that required Python, the first one asks for a specific Python version wins.

So how can we force the version of Python that vim will load? We load it before any other plugin, by placing these lines in the top of `.vimrc`

```
if has('python3')
endif
```

Do it at your own risk, because it might break your plugins.